# what is the error in the security group line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

security_groups = ["{aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id}"]

getting the below error for the particular line

aws_instance.jenkinsec2: Creating...

Error: Error launching instance, possible mismatch of Security Group IDs and Names. See AWS Instance docs here: https://terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html.

```
    AWS Error: InvalidParameterValue: Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty
    status code: 400, request id: d2184bbd-e63d-49d3-a77b-3997b140ffe0
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an [mcve] of what you've tried and then show the error with as much context as possible also formatted in a code block please? Also you shouldn't be using the `security_groups` parameter unless you are running an EC2 Classic (non VPC) account as mentioned in the `aws_instance` resource docs you linked.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it would the following in 0.11:

```
security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id}"]
```

or in 0.12 and above:

```
security_groups = [aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem. I've solved changing id for name. Like this:

```
security_groups = [ aws_security_group.<SG_NAME>.name ]
```